# Run shell script without showing all logs

Tags: shell-script

Is it possible to run this script in a kind of 'silent' mode, so that only the `echo`'s are displayed? All the other output should be stored in a log file.

```
#!/bin/sh

which docker && docker --version | grep "Docker version"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "already existing"
else
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
    apt-cache policy docker-engine

    sudo apt-get install -y \
        linux-image-extra-$(uname -r) \
        linux-image-extra-virtual \
        docker-engine

    sudo service docker start

    which docker && docker --version | grep "Docker version"

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "installed correctly"
    else
        echo "installation failed" >&2
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can if you change some lines:

```
#!/bin/sh

which docker && docker --version | grep -q "Docker version"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "already existing"
else
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y 2>&1 >something.log
    apt-cache policy docker-engine 2>&1 >something.log

    sudo apt-get install -y \
        linux-image-extra-$(uname -r) \
        linux-image-extra-virtual \
        docker-engine 2>&1 >something.log

    sudo service docker start 2>&1 >something.log

    which docker && docker --version | grep -q "Docker version"

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "installed correctly"
    else
        echo "installation failed" >&2
    fi
fi
```

Comment: But this will discard every output, right? Can I write everything in a something.log file?

Comment: @user3142695 Made the change, except for the lines with `grep`, I don't think you would need those in the log file. BTW, there is a lot which could be done better, e.g. `which` shouldn't be used and instead of checking `$?` you could put the previous lines into the `if`s.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. Could you please show me how it has to be done. `if [ which docker && docker --version | grep "Docker version" -eq 0 ]` isn't the correct syntax... `which docker` should give me the path of docker...

Comment: @user3142695 No need for `[`/`]`, there, you are just checking the exit codes of the command.

Comment: @user3142695 See also http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#test (`test` is basically the same as `[`).